# Xcode finding a nil variable where none should be when methods is called from another ViewController class

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, xcode11, swift5

I got midway through creating a MacOS app (my first app ever that isn't part of a "Your First App" tutorial) involving a lot of user options in the main window and became fed up with the fact that my ViewController file had become an unwieldy mess that was not going to be maintainable in the long run.

I decided to break it input multiple view controllers in smaller chunks to make it more manageable using container views in UIBuilder for embedding views, but all the tutorials I found were either for outdated versions of Xcode/Swift, or were about managing multiple views in iOS, so I had to extrapolate a little, and I may have done it wrong.

Now I'm getting an error on a method in one ViewController when the method is called by another ViewController, even though that method works find when called by its own view controller.

Either I'm missing something obvious, or I set things up wrong.

Global variables:

```
var inputPathUrl = URL?
var outputExtension: String = ""
```

@IBOutlets and local properties for the `InOutViewController` class:

```
@IBOutlet weak var inputTextDisplay: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var outputTextDisplay: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var inputBrowseButton: NSButton!
@IBOutlet weak var outputBrowseButton: NSButton!

var outputDirectoryUrl: URL?
var inputFilePath: String = ""
```

@IBOutlets for the `OptionsViewController` class

```
@IBOutlet weak var Button1: NSButton!
@IBOutlet weak var Button2: NSButton!
@IBOutlet weak var Button3: NSButton!
@IBOutlet weak var Button4: NSButton!
@IBOutlet weak var Button5: NSButton!
```

Methods for the `InOutViewController` class:

```
@IBAction func InputBrowseClicked(\_ sender: Any) {  
    let inputPanel = NSOpenPanel()  
    inputPanel.canChooseFiles = true  
    inputPanel.canChooseDirectories = false  
    inputPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false  
    inputPanel.allowedFileTypes = \["aax"\]  
    let userChoice = inputPanel.runModal()  
    switch userChoice{  
        case .OK : 
        if let inputFileChosen = inputPanel.url {
            inputFileUrl = inputFileChosen // define global variable that will be called by other methods in other classes to check if an input file has been chosen
            updateInputText() // call methods to display path strings in text fields
            updateOutputText()
        }
        case .cancel :
            print("user cancelled")
        default :
            break
        }
    } 

@IBAction func outputBrowseClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    let outputPanel = NSOpenPanel()
    outputPanel.canChooseFiles = false
    outputPanel.canChooseDirectories = true
    outputPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    let userChoice = outputPanel.runModal()
    switch userChoice{
        case .OK :
            if let outputUrl = outputPanel.url {
                outputDirectoryUrl = outputUrl
                updateOutputText()
        }
        case .cancel :
            print("user cancelled")
        default:
            break
    }
}

func updateInputText() {
    // call getOutputOption method to see which radio button is selected 
    OptionsViewController().getOutputOption() 
        if inputFileUrl != nil {
            inputFilePath = inputFileUrl!.path
            inputTextDisplay.stringValue = inputFilePath
         }
    }
func updateOutputText() {
    // derive output file path and name from input if no output location is chosen 
    if inputFileUrl != nil && outputDirectoryUrl == nil {
        let outputDirectory = inputFileUrl!.deletingPathExtension()
        let outputDirectoryPath = outputDirectory.path
        let outputPath = outputDirectoryPath + "(outputExtension)"
        outputTextDisplay.stringValue = outputPath
    } else if inputFileUrl != nil && outputDirectoryUrl != nil {
     // derive default file name from input but use selected output path if one is chosen
        let outputDirectoryPath = outputDirectoryUrl!.path
        let outputFile = inputFileUrl!.deletingPathExtension()
        let outputFilename = outputFile.lastPathComponent
        // derive file extension from getOutputOption method of OptionsViewController class
        let outputPath = outputDirectoryPath + "/" + outputFilename + "(outputExtension)"
        outputTextDisplay.stringValue = outputPath
       }
    }
```

That last line (`outputTextDisplay.stringValue = outputPath`) is what I'm getting the fatal error on, but ONLY when I call this method from the `@IBAction` for the output format radio buttons in `OptionsViewController` to update the output display when a different file extension is chosen. When I call the method from the actions methods in `InOutViewController` it works fine.

Here are the `@IBAction` method and `getOutputOption` methods from the `OptionsViewController` class:

```
@IBAction func radioButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    getOutputOption()
        // update display with new file extension
    InOutViewController().updateOutputText()
}

func getOutputOption() {
    // make sure an input file has been chosen
        if inputFileUrl != nil {
                // check which radio button is selected and derive output file format based on selection
                // not sure why I need to specify the button isn't nil, since one is ALWAYS selected, but I was getting a fatal error without doing so
        if (Button1 != nil) && Button1.state == .on {
            outputExtension = ".extA"
        } else if (Button2 != nil) && Button2.state == .on {
            outputExtension = ".extB"
        } else if (Button3 != nil) && Button3.state == .on {
            outputExtension = ".extC"
        } else if (Button4 != nil) && Button4.state == .on {
            outputExtension = ".extD"
        } else {
            outputExtension = ".extE"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but like I said, it's my first time working with multiple view controllers and I'm not sure I've implemented them properly, and I've only been coding for a few weeks, so I can't spot where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Where is outputTextDisplay defined? Is it a property of InOutViewController? Show its declaration. How does it get a value? Show the code that assign a value to it. **What** is it? (A UITextField? Some other view class?)

Comment: Sorry. It's an NSTextField declared in the @IBOutlets. Edited to add that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that `outputTextDisplay` is an IBOutlet in `InOutViewController`, and it is declared as implicitly unwrapped. (Something like this: )

```
var outputTextDisplay: UITextField!
```

If you reference such a variable from one of the IBActions in your `InOutViewController`, all is well because at that point your view controller's views are loaded.

If, on the other hand, you call `updateOutputText()` from another view controller, your `InOutViewController`'s views may not have been loaded yet, so the outlet for outputTextDisplay is still nil. When a variable is declared as implicitly unwrapped (using a `!` at the end of the type) then any time you reference it, the compiler force-unwraps it, and if it's nil, you crash.

You should change your `updateOutputText()` to use `?` to unwrap the variable. That stops implicitly unwrapped optionals from crashing. Something like this:

```
func updateOutputText() {
    // derive output file path and name from input if no output location is chosen 
    if inputFileUrl != nil && outputDirectoryUrl == nil {
        let outputDirectory = inputFileUrl!.deletingPathExtension()
        let outputDirectoryPath = outputDirectory.path
        let outputPath = outputDirectoryPath + "(outputExtension)"
        outputTextDisplay?.stringValue = outputPath //Note the `?`
    } else if inputFileUrl != nil && outputDirectoryUrl != nil {
     // derive default file name from input but use selected output path if one is chosen
        let outputDirectoryPath = outputDirectoryUrl!.path
        let outputFile = inputFileUrl!.deletingPathExtension()
        let outputFilename = outputFile.lastPathComponent
        // derive file extension from getOutputOption method of OptionsViewController class
        let outputPath = outputDirectoryPath + "/" + outputFilename + "(outputExtension)"
        outputTextDisplay?.stringValue = outputPath  //Note the `?`
       }
    }
}
```

The code `outputTextDisplay?.stringValue = outputPath` uses "optional chaining", which causes the compiler to check if `outputTextDisplay` is nil, and stop executing the code if it is.

Note that if you make that change, your string value won't get installed into your `outputTextDisplay` field when you call the `updateOutputText()` function. You'll need to install the value after `viewDidLoad()` is called. (Perhaps in your viewDidLoad or in viewWillAppear.)

### Edit:

This code:

```
@IBAction func radioButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    getOutputOption()
        // update display with new file extension
    InOutViewController().updateOutputText()
}
```

Is very wrong. In response to the user clicking a radio button, the `InOutViewController()` bit creates a throw-away instance of an `InOutViewController`, tries to call its `updateOutputText()` method, and then forgets about the newly created `InOutViewController`. Don't do that.

You need a way to keep track fo the child view controllers that are on-screen. To show you how to do that you'll need to explain how your various view controllers are being created. Are you using embed segues?

Comment: Thank you, that solved my crash! My file extension isn't changing when I click a different radio button, but I'm pretty sure I can troubleshoot that one.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem you should accept it.

Comment: Oh ok sorry. Still figuring SO out. Done.

Comment: Accepting the first/best answer to your question that solves the problem is pretty much a requirement. Up-voting good answers is optional, but encouraged. (You'll need to get some more reputation points before you will be able to up-vote.)

Comment: Also, after you've written a question, but before you post it, go through an exercise. Review your post from the perspective of somebody who knows nothing about your problem. Think about the information such a person will need. Have I shown all the relevant information, and removed the extraneous "boilerplate" code? What questions would a reader need to ask in order to help? Edit your question to provide that information, and remove code that **isn't** relevant.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying. That's part of why I omitted the @IBOutlets to begin with. I think I assumed people would know what "inputTextDisplay" would refer to. What I'm actually struggling most with is removing extraneous code, because some of the issues I'm encountering are so convoluted and I'm so new to all this that I'm not sure what people need to know to help me with them. Right now I have an issue that might be a Swift problem or might be an FFmpeg problem or might be both, and every time I try to summarize I end up writing a novel.

Comment: Hi. Somehow I missed the edit/addendum to your answer until I was going back to revisit your answer just now. I couldn't get the multiple view controllers to work for me and went back to doing it with a single view controller, then once again thought better of it and decided to do it properly.

Yes, I am using embed segues with container views. I have three of them. My InOutView Controller, which handles my input/output browse buttons and path display text fields, my Options view controller which handles my popup menu (I gave up on radio buttons) and one that handles execution and output log

Comment: Honestly I'm not even sure I should be using multiple view controllers. All I know is that there are a lot of tutorials talking about the evils of Massive View Controller and saying not to do that and focusing on using child view controllers and/or container views. I wonder if really I shouldn't be using different classes/.swift files that aren't view controllers, but I can't find tutorials about when and how it's appropriate to do that.

Comment: If you're just getting started with Swift and iOS development then you need to walk before you can run. I'd say start off using one view controller with the logic in the view controller. Master that. Then, as your view controllers get more complex, learn how to break them into logical "lego blocks" using container views and embed segues.

Comment: Then, once you master container views, learn how to separate out the business logic from the view controller and make your view controllers ONLY manage the display of information. That reduces massive view controller disease, and makes your code easier to test and support.